# How to disable the SSL certificates for Java application in github actions?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, github-actions

I am getting the error while uploading Java artifacts in nexus repo. below is the screenshot.

GitHub Actions workflow code

```
        uses: sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repo-github-action@master
        with:
          serverUrl: https://test.xyz/repository/maven-testreleases/
          username: test
          password: ${{ secrets.pwd }}
          format: maven3
          repository: maven-test-releases
          coordinates: groupId=com.exampleartifactId=app version=1.0.0
          assets: extension=jar
          filename: target/*.jar
```

```
com.sonatype.nexus.api.exception.RepositoryManagerException: Upload component was unable to complete
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.fg.a(SourceFile:96)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.fg.a(SourceFile:65)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.ff.upload(SourceFile:157)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.ff.upload(SourceFile:140)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.RepositoryManagerV3Client$upload.call(Unknown Source)
    at NexusPublisher.run(NexusPublisher.groovy:64)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SourceFile:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SourceFile:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(SourceFile:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(SourceFile:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(SourceFile:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(SourceFile:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(SourceFile:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(SourceFile:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(SourceFile:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(SourceFile:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:165)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.fg.a(SourceFile:84)

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I think I need to disable the SSL certificate using some command in workflow.

- name: Disable the ssl certificates
  run: mvn -Dmaven.resolver.transport=wagon -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true clean package

but this one also not working..

please suggest.

Comment: If you do not care about ssl, why not disable it from your actual server? `https://test.xyz`

Comment: @D.T this is just POC.. so as of now just want to make sure my artifacts should upload into the bin repo..